# Add a new todo without jumping to it?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to add a todo in org-mode without jumping to the heading. For now the best solution for me is to refile. Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, but in most cases, people use [Org capture](https://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html) to add a new heading to one of their common files (and maybe refile from there, depending on their workflow).  See e.g [Organize your Life in Plain Text](https://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html) for some ideas.

Comment: @NickD org capture with refile  is exactly, what I was looking for. Thank you for always helping.